# Multiple Languages Support For Sharepoint App

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

I have developed an app for SharePoint and it is available on SharePoint app store. Currently it is in English only. Now i want to add support in multiple languages such as German, Japanese, French. Do i need to make changes only in my code part or while publishing this app, if we choose different languages, will Microsoft take care of it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you yourself should make sure the App supports a multilingual user interface.

In your App solution add resources (`.resx`) for all the languages you want to support and implement it everywhere in your code where text should be translated.

[This MSDN article should get you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179919%28v=office.15%29.aspx).